# Table overflowing on HTML page

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table, overflow

I'm finishing up a midterm project for an HTMl course and I'm working on my last page. Problem is, the table overflows to the right (when the browser isn't maximized) and I can't figure out how to fix it. Can anyone help?

I can't post a pic. (No rep)

The HTML:

```
<div id="rightcolumn">  
 <h2>Fuel Cells</h2>
  <!--3 Column by 3 Row Layout using a Table-->
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="6">
   <caption>Fuel Cells as a Source of Green Energy</caption>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">The research and development of fuel cells is extremely important. Fuel cells are an important technology because they use hydrogen to create energy. Hydrogen is the most plentiful element in our universe, quite unlike oil. If the US ran on fuel cells we  would finally be independent from oil. Also, hydrogen doesn&rsquo;t need to be  &ldquo;mined&rdquo; like oil. If we no longer needed oil we would save on the price we have  been paying for decades. Hydrogen is both extremely abundant and a renewable  resource. If hydrogen was used as our primary power source we wouldn&rsquo;t ever  need to worry about running out of it, like we do with oil and other fossil  fuels. A cloudy day can stop solar panels from generating much electricity and  a still day can stop wind power. With hydrogen however, weather wouldn&rsquo;t affect  the quantity of power fuel cells produce. This makes fuel cells far more  reliable than other, alternative forms of &ldquo;green&rdquo; energy.
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td ><img src="FuelCellDiagram.png" width="335" height="232" alt="How Fuel Cells Work" /></td>
    <td><img src="FuelCellhome.png" width="345" height="250" alt="Fuel Cell Powering Home" /></td>
    <td><img src="FCCar.GIF" width="400" height="347" alt="How Fuel Cells power Cars" /></td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Fuel cells are important  because of their harmless byproducts. Water and heat, the byproducts, aren&rsquo;t  dangerous and could actually be useful. The heat generated by fuel cells could  be used to heat homes or water, making fuel cells even more efficient. Fuel cells would allow us to power our cars as well as our homes. This would  lead to an end of the use of gasoline or battery powered vehicles. Although  cars are becoming more efficient, they are unable to match the efficiency of  fuel cells. Our current gas powered vehicles produce harmful pollutants during  fuel combustion. Battery powered vehicles are also harmful because of the  pollutants that are byproducts of both creating and disposing of them. If the  world could end its dependence on oil and transition to fuel cells, our  pollution levels would be a fraction of what they are now. In China, many  cities are filled with smog because of the way they are powered. If China were  to replace their coal plants with fuel cells, the ever increasing smog  throughout China would begin to fade. Also, we  would no longer have to worry about pollution from oil spills or oil wells. 
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
<!--End of Columns/Table-->

</div>
```

and the CSS is:

```
#container { 
        margin: auto;  
        width:80%;
        min-width:700px;
    background-color:#93A5C4;
    color:#000000;
    border: 2px double #000000;
}
#rightcolumn { 
        margin-left:140px;  
        background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#000000;
    padding:10px;
}
td, tr, th {
padding: 10px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align: left;
}
```

I can't edit the rightcolumn CSS though because I need it like that to display the other pages properly and I'm only allowed to use one CSS sheet for the entire site.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any HTML with the ID "container", and the "rightcolumn" DIV surrounds the entire table. Is this what you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution would be to add a style of "overflow:scroll" in your declaration for the rightcolumn div.

```
<div id="rightcolumn" style="overflow:scroll">
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! If anyone knows of any other, better fixes please let me know!

Comment: could you post the full HTML and CSS for this page. It will help shed some light on other possible solutions.

Comment: Here is a link to everything. The specific part I'm having trouble with is the "Fuel Cell" page. It scrolls now, but if you remove the overflow style recommended above, you'll see what I mean.